# Php split string on different characters

Tags: php, regex, split

I want to split a string on different characters and I want to know what the 'splitter' is.

The String can be for example:

```
"address=test"
"number>20"
"age<=55"
```

In these cases I want to get the name, the seperator and the value in an array.

```
array[0]='address';
array[1]='=';
array[2]='test';
```

The separators are =,==,!=,<,>,>=,<=.

Can anyone tell me to deal with this?

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]+)(=|==|!=|<|>|>=|<=)([a-zA-Z]+)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$strings = array("address=test","number>20","age<=55");
foreach($strings as $s)
{
  preg_match('/([^=!<>]+)(=|==|!=|<|>|>=|<=)([^=!<>]+)/', $s, $matches);
  echo 'Left: ',$matches[1],"\n";
  echo 'Seperator: ',$matches[2],"\n";
  echo 'Right: ',$matches[3],"\n\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Left: address
Seperator: =
Right: test

Left: number
Seperator: >
Right: 20

Left: age
Seperator: <=
Right: 55
```

Edit: This method using the [^=!<>] makes the method to prefer failing completely over giving unexpected results. Meaning that `foo=bar<3` will fail to be recognized. This can of course be changed to fit your needs :-).

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work:

```
$seps=array('=', '==', '!=', '<', '>', '>=', '<=');

$lines=array(
    "address=test",
    "number>20",
    "age<=55"
    );

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $result=array();
    foreach ($seps as $sep) {
        $offset=strpos($line, $sep);
        if (!($offset===false)) {
            $result[0]=substr($line, 0, $offset);
            $result[1]=substr($line, $offset, 1);
            $result[2]=substr($line, $offset+1);
        }
    }
    print_r($result);
}
```

You can then test if `$result` has anything in it (split character was found) by using `count($result)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/(\S)(=|==|!=|<|>|>=|<=)(\S)/', $subject, $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick 'n dirty:

```
$parts = preg_split('/[<>=!]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list($key, $splitter, $val) = split('[^a-z0-9]+', $str);
echo 'Key: '.$key.'; Splitter: '.$splitter.'; Val: '.$val;
```

This assumes that your keys and vals are alphanumeric. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$str = "address=test";
preg_match("/(?<k>.+?)(?<operator>[=|==|!=|<|>|>=|<=]{1,2})(?<v>.+?)/",$str,$match); 
$match["k"] //addres
$match["operator"] //=
$match["v"] //test
```

Comment: Review this: "[=|==|!=|<|>|>=|<=]{1,2}". This should be equivalent to [=!><|]{1,2}. That's probably not what you wanted. You probably wanted either [=!<>]{1,2} or ([=|==|!=|<|>|>=|<=])